# Help to understand this encoder timer tick code

Tags: avr, timer, encoder

Could somebody please please help me understand the following code. Its running on atmega128 @ 16 Mhz. Its reading an encoder pulse. Uses timer3. The encoder CHA is connected to PIND2 (INT2) which gets triggered whenever there is an interrupt from low to high. CHB of the encoder is connected to PINE7.

I cant quite understand why TCNT3>>3 in this case.

```
SIGNAL(SIG_INTERRUPT2) 
{ 
   timer3_stop(); 
   Right_Odometer_Period = TCNT3>>3; 
   right_overflow_occurred = timer3_overflowed; 
   timer3_start(); 

   if ((PINE & 0x80) != 0) 
   { 
      right_odometer++; 
      right_up = 1; 

   } 
   else 
   { 
      right_odometer--; 
      right_up = 0; 
      Right_Odometer_Period = Right_Odometer_Period * -1; 
   } 
   Right_Velocity = Right_Odometer_Period; 
   averaging_array[array_ptr++] = Right_Odometer_Period; 
   if (array_ptr == 32) 
   { 
      arraysum = 0; 
      for (int i = 0; i<32; i++) 
      { 
       arraysum += averaging_array[i]; 
      } 
      average = arraysum>>5; 
      array_ptr = 0; 
   } 
} 

void timer3_init(void) 
{ 
   TCCR3A = 0x00; 
   TCNT3 = 0X0000; 
   ETIMSK = (ETIMSK | (1<<TOIE3)); 
   timer3_start(); 
} 

void timer3_start(void) 
{ 
   TCNT3 = 0X0000; 
   timer3_overflowed = 0; 
   TCCR3B = (1<<CS30)|(0<<CS31)|(0<<CS32); 
} 

void timer3_stop(void) 
{ 
   TCCR3B &= ~(1<<CS30)|(1<<CS31)|(1<<CS32); 
} 

SIGNAL(SIG_OVERFLOW3) 
{ 
   TCNT3 = 0X0000; 
        Right_Velocity = 0; 
   timer3_overflowed = 1;    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best guess I can come up with is that the `>>3` (divide by 8) is an attempt to prevent going beyond the size of the variable `arraysum`.  Since `TCNT3` is a 16 bit counter, if there wasn't some sort of scaling factor, you could easily end up with a garbage value for `arraysum`.

That said, the `>>3` probably wouldn't completely solve this problem.  I think it would depend upon how quickly the encoder is getting spun and the clock speed of the mega128.  If each tick on D2 happens to occur when `TCNT3` is very large, this algorithm for determining rotational speed is going to have issues.